# WTP does not pick up JSP as servlet mapping

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, eclipse-wtp, embedded-tomcat-7

(I have tried looking for this particular scenario in different forums, but nobody seems to have posted this scenario.)

I have a web application in which I have the following servlet mapping:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mine.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My web application provides the `mine.TestServlet` servlet class, which is compiled separately as `controller.jar`.
I have created a separate WTP Tomcat instance which points to an external Tomcat installation and added controller.jar to its runtime.

Everything works as expected with this setup. I have tried to run the Tomcat from its startup script externally and usng eclipse's Server management console. Both ways the above works as expected.

Now, I changed the `web.xml` to point to a JSP in the servlet mapping:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/jsp/test.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The JSP is deployed in the webapp in Tomcat.

Again, when I run the Tomcat instance outside Eclipse, everything works as expected.

*But when I run the Tomcat instance from within eclipse, it cannot locate `test.jsp`. I understand this is because I have not specified the location of the JSP anywhere in the Tomcat configuration.*

**Where can I specify this so the JSP gets picked up by the Tomcat instance when run from within eclipse?**

Please let me know if you need more information in order to understand the issue.

Comment: Check the project's Deployment Assembly property page. Is that file going where you think it is? (Assuming you're not using Maven)

Comment: @nitind Thanks for your response! Remember, I am not trying to deploy a dynamic web project from within eclipse. my web app is built separately, I only have the Tomcat instance running within Eclipse. I am debugging only the Java components (for example, components within controller.jar), which is why I have it set up this way.

Comment: Ok, but when you run Tomcat from within Eclipse, you're basically deploying to that instance of Tomcat. Check the contents of your workspace's .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/ directory.

Comment: @nitind Not really, right? When I create a Tomcat pointing to an external installation (3rd option), that instance is not created in the workspace. I am not deploying a web project, but only adding the Java project to the Tomcat runtime. http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#What_configuration_option_determines_whether_the_Tomcat_server_uses_a_separate_instance_or_the_instance_from_the_Tomcat_installation.3F

Comment: *How* are you adding it? And where is the JSP in the project, then?

Comment: @nitind You can add a Java library as a runtime classpath entry in a Tomcat WTP instance by double clicking on the server -> Open Launch Configuration -> Classpath tab. The JSP is deployed directly in Tomcat, it does not belong to any project.